# Adding a <script> node on top of <body> from javascript in <head>

Tags: javascript, html

I want to insert some javascript code,

1. That should be run before other javascript codes in the `<body>`run.
2. As they manipulate html in `<body>`, that are inside `<body>`.

Normally i would put this javascript in a `<script>` tag right after the opening `<body>` tag. But I am not writing the html directly. Its generated for me by a program. ([react-storybook](https://github.com/kadirahq/react-storybook)). Its API allows to inject html inside `<head>` but not `<body>`.

```
<head>
  <script></script>  <-- I can inject a script tag here
</head>
<body>
  <script></script>  <-- I can't directly add this script tag but I need one here

  <script>other js</script>
</body>
```

I tried putting my js in a `document` `load` event handler, but they run after body is completely loaded so other js has already run.

I tried putting my js directly in the head then my js can't use `appendChild` on body, because at that point `document.body` is null.

Is there a way to insert a script tag satisfying both above requirements with accessing only the `<head>`?

Comment: Do you mean that you are putting the loading of the script there, or a script tag with the function?

Comment: *"I tried putting my js directly in the head then my js can't use appendChild on body, because at that point document.body is null."* Well wait, are you trying to just output elements to the body, or act on elements that *other* code is writing to the body?

Comment: Could you please explain, what is the necessity of doing this?

Comment: T.J just output elements to the body.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see any way to do this without probably breaking the tool you're trying to work within and doing some fairly nasty things. I suspect there's a better way to solve your underlying problem.

> I tried putting my js directly in the head then my js can't use `appendChild` on `body`, because at that point `document.body` is null...

It's **nasty and probably a bad idea**, but you could force the body to be started:

```
document.write("<body>");
```

At that point, the parser will create the `body` element. You can then use `appendChild` (or just continue using the evil `document.write`). When the body is started again later in the normal course fo things, that second opening tag will be ignored.

It's **not a good idea**. react-storybook is open source. If there isn't a way to achieve your actual goal with it already, I suggest modifying it so you can rather than doing something like the above.

Here's an example, tested and working in Chrome, Firefox, IE11, IE8, and iOS Safari.
([Live copy on JSBin](http://output.jsbin.com/nimogomobe)):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Example</title>
  <script>
    (function() {
      var d = document.createElement("div");
      d.innerHTML =
        "This is the element appended to the body element " +
        "that we forced to be created using the evil " +
        "<code>document.write</code>";
      document.write("<body>");
      document.body.appendChild(d);
    })();
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
This is the first element inside the body element in the markup.
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Huh. That's very unexpected.

Comment: @Quentin: Yeah, the relationship between `document.write` and the parser is interactive, somewhat counter-intuitive, and best left alone by not using `document.write`. :-)

Comment: Thanks, I can use this for now. Will eventually fork storybook and submit a PR for something nicer.

Answer (score 2):

> I tried putting my js directly in the head then my js can't use `appendChild` on body, because at that point `document.body` is null.

[MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to the rescue!
You can simply wait for the `<body>` tag to be parsed:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script>
new MutationObserver(function(records, self)
{
    for(var i = 0; i < records.length; ++i)
    {
        for(var j = 0; j < records[i].addedNodes.length; ++j)
        {
            if(records[i].addedNodes[j].nodeName == 'BODY')
            {
                self.disconnect();
                console.log('herp');
                /*
                At this point, the body exists, but nothing inside it has been parsed yet.
                document.body might be available, but to be safe, you can use:
                var body = records[i].addedNodes[j];
                */
            }
        }
    }
}).observe(document.documentElement,
{
    childList: true,
});
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>console.log('derp');</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Save this to an HTML file, open it in your browser, and you should see this in the console (indicating that the "herp" part runs before the "derp" one (note: Firefox seems to discard message order if the console is opened after the page loads, but the "herp" part is actually still running before the "derp" one)):

```
herp
derp
```

(Note: The above code won't work as a stack snippet, because everything is placed in the `<body>` tag there.)

Now just to be safe, I'd add a check to see if `document.body` is already set, and only set up the MutationObserver if that isn't the case:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script>
function onBodyLoaded(body)
{
    console.log('herp');
    /* Do whatever you want with "body" here. */
}
if(document.body)
{
    onBodyLoaded(document.body)
}
else
{
    new MutationObserver(function(records, self)
    {
        for(var i = 0; i < records.length; ++i)
        {
            for(var j = 0; j < records[i].addedNodes.length; ++j)
            {
                if(records[i].addedNodes[j].nodeName == 'BODY')
                {
                    self.disconnect();
                    onBodyLoaded(records[i].addedNodes[j]);
                }
            }
        }
    }).observe(document.documentElement,
    {
        childList: true,
    });
}
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>console.log('derp');</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This way you might not have to add a `<script>` tag to your body at all, but just place the code you want to run there inside the `onBodyLoaded` function.
If you do need to add a script tag though, you can do so with:

```
function onBodyLoaded(body)
{
    body.appendChild(document.createElement('script')).src = 'https://example.com/my.js';
}
```

or

```
function onBodyLoaded(body)
{
    body.appendChild(document.createElement('script')).innerHTML = 'document.write("hi there")';
}
```

Note that IE 10 and earlier don't support `MutationObserver`. IE 11 and any other browser from this decade should work though.

Comment: Gets good results with Chrome and Firefox: http://output.jsbin.com/jicaleqefa Sadly with IE11 it doesn't run the observer callback until the end of the body has been parsed and scripts within it have been run.

Comment: Side note: IE9 and IE10 both supported the old Mutation Events (enough to do the above, anyway), so one could probably pursue this technique even down to IE9 with enough effort.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for the info. Can't test due to lack of an IE 9, but [this polyfill](https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/blob/master/src/MutationObserver/MutationObserver.js) looks like it should do the job for IE 9 and IE 10. I might try and fix the IE 11 behaviour later, if I have time.